# Cycles - Baking to image problem (looks like seams on the image, but not sure)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Am totally lost as to why this is happening.  I'm quite new to Blender, but have been trying to use nodes lately.  I'm trying to make some game assets, and am baking my material to an image, but I am getting what appears to be seams showing on the image.

I have no clue how I would UV unwrap my model (low poly rocks / mountains), so I use the Smart UV Project option, so am not sure if that is the cause or not.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your face is non-planar.
Go in Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), enter face selection mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, Face), select your face (RMB). Open the Mesh menu, Cleanup, Make Planar Faces.
[image: make planar]
This should fix it, but can make surrounding faces non-planar...

Comment: Thanks a ton, that actually solved a few other issues I had as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the mesh topology. Try to join vertices on these face (with <kbd>j</kbd>) and check with <kbd>w</kbd>> *remove doubles* if some vertices aren't welded.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this could be that with your current settings you are actually bake lighting into your texture. You might want to deselect "Direct" and "Indirect" in your Bake Type options and try only "Diffuse".

[image: Bake Type Options]

Comment: Oh wow, that makes a big difference and actually fixed a few other issues I had when baking.  Sorry I can't accept this as well, as it has helped greatly.  I didn't really know what those 2 settings did, so left them as default. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JacketPotatoeFan - no prob. You could still upvote my answer, though...

Comment: Soon as I get 15 rep, I certainly will :)